# Problems with DynamicMethod to invoke generic methods

Tags: c#, system.reflection, reflection.emit

I have problems calling functions such as Int64.ToString() in a routine that calls generic methods via DynamicMethod.

The problem seems to be that the dynamically generated routine receives the pointer to the (int) object instead of the value, so ToString() is applied to the pointer, returning the pointer converted to string.

This is the whole code, which shows that the routine works fine when calling methods in defined classes (Person class), but fails with Int64.ToString():

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public delegate object FastInvokeHandler(object target, object[] paramters);

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestInvokePerson();     // WORKS!
            TestInvokeToString();   // FAILS!
        }

        static void TestInvokePerson()
        {
            Type t = typeof(Person);
            MethodInfo methodInfo = t.GetMethod("Say");
            Person person = new Person();
            string word = "hello";
            Person p = null;
            object[] param = new object[] { word, p, 3, 3 };
            FastInvokeHandler fastInvoker = GetMethodInvoker(methodInfo);
            fastInvoker(person, param);
        }

        static void TestInvokeToString()
        {
            Type t = typeof(System.Int64);
            MethodInfo methodInfo = t.GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);
            System.Int64 int_value = new System.Int64();
            int_value = 1;
            FastInvokeHandler fastInvoker = GetMethodInvoker(methodInfo);
            var str = fastInvoker(int_value, null);
            Console.WriteLine("1 converted is {0}", str);
        }

        private static FastInvokeHandler GetMethodInvoker(MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            DynamicMethod dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod(string.Empty, typeof(object), new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(object[]) }, methodInfo.DeclaringType.Module, true);
            ILGenerator il = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
            ParameterInfo[] ps = methodInfo.GetParameters();
            Type[] paramTypes = new Type[ps.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < paramTypes.Length; i++)
            {
                if (ps[i].ParameterType.IsByRef)
                    paramTypes[i] = ps[i].ParameterType.GetElementType();
                else
                    paramTypes[i] = ps[i].ParameterType;
            }
            LocalBuilder[] locals = new LocalBuilder[paramTypes.Length];


            for (int i = 0; i < paramTypes.Length; i++)
            {
                locals[i] = il.DeclareLocal(paramTypes[i], true);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < paramTypes.Length; i++)
            {
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
                EmitFastInt(il, i);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_Ref);
                EmitCastToReference(il, paramTypes[i]);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, locals[i]);
            }
            if (!methodInfo.IsStatic)
            {
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < paramTypes.Length; i++)
            {
                if (ps[i].ParameterType.IsByRef)
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca_S, locals[i]);
                else
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, locals[i]);
            }
            if (methodInfo.IsStatic)
                il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, methodInfo, null);
            else
                il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, methodInfo, null);
            if (methodInfo.ReturnType == typeof(void))
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
            else
                EmitBoxIfNeeded(il, methodInfo.ReturnType);

            for (int i = 0; i < paramTypes.Length; i++)
            {
                if (ps[i].ParameterType.IsByRef)
                {
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
                    EmitFastInt(il, i);
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, locals[i]);
                    if (locals[i].LocalType.IsValueType)
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, locals[i].LocalType);
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref);
                }
            }

            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            FastInvokeHandler invoder = (FastInvokeHandler)dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(FastInvokeHandler));
            return invoder;
        }

        private static void EmitCastToReference(ILGenerator il, System.Type type)
        {
            if (type.IsValueType)
            {
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, type);
            }
            else
            {
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, type);
            }
        }

        private static void EmitBoxIfNeeded(ILGenerator il, System.Type type)
        {
            if (type.IsValueType)
            {
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, type);
            }
        }

        private static void EmitFastInt(ILGenerator il, int value)
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                case -1:
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_M1);
                    return;
                case 0:
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
                    return;
                case 1:
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
                    return;
                case 2:
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_2);
                    return;
                case 3:
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_3);
                    return;
                case 4:
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_4);
                    return;
                case 5:
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_5);
                    return;
                case 6:
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_6);
                    return;
                case 7:
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_7);
                    return;
                case 8:
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_8);
                    return;
            }

            if (value > -129 && value < 128)
            {
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, (SByte)value);
            }
            else
            {
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, value);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Convert()
        {
            return "hi";
        }
        public void Say(ref string word, out Person p, int avi, int test)
        {
            word = "ttt" + avi.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Person::Say");
            p = new Person();
        }
    }
    }
```

Any ideas how to support such function?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have to unbox the long, add `il.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox, typeof(long))` inside the `if (!methodInfo.IsStatic)` branch. And yes, this will complicate matters.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You put in on the right track! :)